# Alternate the page orientation(portrait to landscape) to render the large tables

Tags: java, itext7, html2pdf

I have a situation in my current Spring Boot 3.0 application where I need to convert HTML content that is larger (tables with many columns) and cause the generated PDF file to have content that overlaps, or with content rendering off the page.

To address this, I intend to perform a comprehensive conversion of the entire HTML file.

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(inputHTML, pdf, converterProperties);
```

Following this, I plan to identify significant tables within the generated PDF file and subsequently rotate the page (A4) containing these large tables. The rotation would entail changing the orientation from portrait to landscape.

I'm open to exploring various solutions to this problem, including the possibility of rotating the page prior to the conversion process.

For reference, the iText packages I'm utilizing are as follows:

```
implementation 'com.itextpdf:html2pdf:4.0.5'
implementation 'com.itextpdf:io:7.2.5'
implementation 'com.itextpdf:kernel:7.2.5'
implementation 'com.itextpdf:layout:7.2.5'
implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext-licensekey:3.1.5'
```